# How to add ng-class to a directive's template?

Tags: angularjs

What is the proper way of adding an `ng-class` expression to an element from inside a directive?

For example:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

Inside `myDirective`, I want to make the element look like this:

```
<div my-directive ng-class="{visible:isVisible}"></div>
```

Should it be done in the compile function's first parameter, the `tElement`?
If so, how? Simply using `setAttribute()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to say

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. `ngClass` toggles the class based on the expression passed in.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a template and replace the original `div` to achieve this:

the directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div ng-class="{visible:isVisible}"></div>',
      replace: true,
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
         $scope.isVisble = true;
      }
   }
})
```

in you html:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

How `isVisible` is set is only an example. You can do this in the directive controller, in the parent scope, in an isolated scope...

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to know how that can be done imperatively.